# mysqli query [Active records Codeigniter]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

> i have a time-table as below

`id  task  to-do-date  to-do-time  status
  1   X     2015|9|19    21:10:1     0
  2   Y     2015|9|19    09:05:3     0
  3   Z     2015|9|17    08:12:3     0
  4   A     2015|9|16    23:10:5     0`

> where date is in  `Y|m|d`  format and Time is in `24 hrs` format ,  `status= 0`  means not Done

Lets `current date 2015|9|19 and time 10:05:3`
Now, I wish to fetch all the tasks which are not done by current date and time sofar, so that result could look like as bellow  with total of not done tasks as well

`id  task  to-do-date  to-do-time  status
  2   Y     2015|9|19    09:05:3     0
  3   Z     2015|9|17    08:12:3     0
  4   A     2015|9|16    23:10:5     0
  total Not-Done-taks =3`

> pls suggest be  `mysqli`  and `CodeIgniter's Active-records`  query as-well for this.
>   Regards.....

Answer (score 1):

You should try this for active records:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('your_table_name');
$this->db->where('to-do-date <= ',date('Y-m-d'));
$this->db->where('to-do-time <= ',date('H:i:s'));
$this->db->where('status',0);
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

and for mysqli:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE to-do-date <= '".date('Y-m-d')."' AND to-do-time <= '".date('H:i:s')."' AND status = 0";
```

Comment: dear Indrasinh Bihola , it is not producing desired result. pls check again

Comment: Ok so what you get and what you want in result update in your question.

Comment: i want tasks with id 2,3,4  whereas as per your query statement i am getting only  2,3

Comment: So Did you get your desired result now??

Comment: ! yes  i got the desired result now with the following  answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('your_table_name');
        $this->db->where('to_do_date < ',date('Y-m-d'));
        $this->db->where('status','0');
        $this->db->or_where('to_do_date',date('Y-m-d'));
        $this->db->where('to_do_time < ',date('H:i:s'));
        $this->db->where('status',0);           
        $skipped = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        foreach ($skipped as $skp) {
            echo $skp['task'], $skp['to_do_date'],$skp['to_do_time'],$skp['status'], "</br>";

        }
```